# Filter array of hashtables

Tags: powershell

I have an array of hashtables and I am trying to filter it to those who has a property value to true, but this what I am doing does not looks good.

```
# object looks like this
$array = @(
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $true }
    @{ Name = 'Second'; Passed = $false }
)

function Filter {
    Param($array)
    $filtered = @()

    foreach ($item in $array) {
        if ($item.Passed = $true) {
            $filtered += $item
        }
    }

    return $filtered
}
```

Is there any other way I can get all elements who has property `Passed = $True` without the need to add those to another array.

Comment: `$newarray = @($array | Where-Object { $_.Passed })`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers won't that catch anything with a Passed that is "truthy"?  (i.e. not just the ones with a value of $true)

Comment: @MikeShepard Yes. But since the key seems to have only boolean values that shouldn't be an issue. Otherwise change the condition to `$_.Passed -eq $true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe your array into a Where-Object like so:

```
$array = @(
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $True }
    @{ Name = 'First'; Passed = $False }
)

$array = $array | Where-Object Passed -EQ $True
```

Comment: Beware that this will not give an array result if the `Where-Object` filter returns less than 2 items.

Comment: Good point, changing it to `$array = @($array | Where-Object Passed -EQ $True)` would fix that.